# Show that for any natural numbers, if $S(x)=S(y)$ then $x=y$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Definition. $0=\emptyset$.

Definition.  $S(x):=x\cup\{x\}$, $S(y):=y\cup\{y\}$.

Definition. $S(x):=x\cup${$x$}.

*Theorem1.* For all natural numbers $x$ and $y$, if $x\in y$ then $x\subseteq y$.

*Theorem2.* For all natural numbers $x$ and $y$ if $S(x)=S(y)$ then $x=y$.

Note that we will use *Theorem1* for proof of *Theorem2*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note (or prove) that for every natural number $x$, if $z=S(x)$ then $\bigcup z=x$. Now use induction to prove the wanted conclusion.

Comment: Edited. I think that using induction is unnecessary. I will wrtite proof-trying without using induction.

Comment: Proof of *Theorem2*. Assume not. i.e., if $S(x)=S(y)$ then $x\neq y$. We know that $x\in x\cup$ {$x$}. Also, by the assumption $x\in y\cup$ {$y$}. Hence, either $x\in y$ or $x\in$ {$y$}. If we show $x\subseteq y$ to use theorem1 ,then we can show $y\subseteq x$. Therefore, we will done. So, how?

Comment: Well, if $x\notin y$, then $x\in\{y\}$. What can you say about any element satisfying $u\in\{v\}$? (You're right, this is much faster and much cleaner. You should finish the argument, and then post it as an answer to your question.)

Comment: I couldn't complete. If $u\in$ {$v$} then we can say $u \subseteq$ {$v$}.Now, exchanging the roles of $x$ and $y$.  We get also $y\in$ {$x$}. So, we get also $y\subseteq$ {$x$}. Now, how can I show $x=y$.

Comment: If $u$ is an element of a singleton $\{v\}$. What possibly could be the relation between $u$ and $v$?

Comment: It could be $u\subseteq$ {$v$} by the theorem1.

Comment: Stop thinking about the natural numbers. If I told you that $u$ is *an* element of the *singleton* $\{v\}$, namely $u$ is an element of a set whose only element is $v$. What can you tell me about $u$ and $v$?

Comment: I can say $u=v$, cannot I?

Comment: Yes. That is correct. Now apply this to your suggestion to consider $x\in y$ or $x\in\{y\}$. If we assume that $x\neq y$, then what can we say about these two options?

Comment: Since by the assumptin $x\neq y$ we can say $x\in$ {$y$}. Hence, we obtain  $x=y$. Thus, we have a contradiction. Therefore, $x=y$.

Comment: We are done, aren't we?

Comment: In conjunction of your previous comment (with the proof of Theorem 2), yes. As a challenge, try to formulate this without an assumption towards contradiction.