# For all natural numbers $x$ and $y$ if $S(x)=S(y)$ then $x=y$.

Tags: set-theory

Definition. $S(x):=x\cup${$x$}.

*Theorem1.* For all natural numbers $x$ and $y$, if $x\in y$ then $x\subseteq y$.

*Theorem2.* For all natural numbers $x$ and $y$ if $S(x)=S(y)$ then $x=y$.

Note that we will use *Theorem1* for proof of *Theorem2*.

Proof of *Theorem2*. Assume not. i.e., if $S(x)=S(y)$ then $x\neq y$. We know that $x\in x\cup$ {$x$}. Also, by the assumption $x\in y\cup$ {$y$}. Hence, either $x\in y$ or $x\in$ {$y$}. So,...

Can you help?

**Answer**: [Show that for any natural numbers, if $S(x)=S(y)$ then $x=y$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1976631/show-that-for-any-natural-numbers-if-sx-sy-then-x-y)

Comment: I feel like I have posted an answer for this question just a few days ago.

Comment: Perhaps it was this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1976631/show-that-for-any-natural-numbers-if-sx-sy-then-x-y/ on *your very question*.

Comment: if $x,y\in \mathbb N$, what does it mean to say that $x\in y$?

Comment: @lulu: In set theory the standard definition for the natural numbers is $0=\varnothing$ and $S(n)=n\cup\{n\}$. In this case, $n<m$ if and only if $n\in m$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes!  Sorry.

Comment: @AsafKaragila  Thanks!  And how does that differ from $x\subseteq y$?

Comment: @lulu: The same way that $n\leq m$ differs from $n<m$. :)

Comment: @AsafKaragila  And again I say, thanks!